# .append not adding .item to .list

Tags: jquery, html

This is part of a lesson on Codecademy.  This is a Jquery lesson.  I cannot figure out how to append the `.item` to the `.list`.  They don't explain it on the website and I have been unable to find an answer that I understand.

### HTML Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>To Do</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### NEW Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('div').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd+ '</div>');
    });
});
```

The problem is that I cannot get `.item` to add into `.list`.  I'm a brand new jQuery user so this is a bit difficult for me to understand. Even **after** fixing the syntax error it is not adding the correct items.

The website is giving me this error:Oops, try again. Make sure to use `.append()` to add your `.item` to your `.list`!

Comment: error here : `">')`. you close append function

Comment: I think there is a syntax problem in this line:

`$('div').append('<div class=".item">' + toAdd+ '</div>');`

Comment: Try not to ask multiple questions. It makes the whole thing confusing. If your original question is answered and you need to ask another question. Ask another question, don't constantly update your original.

Comment: Post your HTML code... Add the code, select it and click the `{}` button from the editor. It should get formatted.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize you posted the code first then formatted it!

Comment: in your code two div  .  $('div')  ؟ is  button or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd+ '</div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked!! I had to add another <div> into the HTML, but after that adding the class name there worked!! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('div').append('<div class=".item">') + toAdd+ '</div>'; // Error on this line
});
```

You are closing function incorrectly. It should be -

```
$('div').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd+ '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The that you have used will not append the elements as you expected.

Try to pass the class and text as an object,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
      var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
      $('div.list').append($('<div>',{"class":"item","text":toAdd}));
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question: *The problem is that I cannot get .item to add into .list*. Or you've not really explained what he's done wrong.

Comment: @Liam I think i have given what OP needs. And i am not sure what am i missing here..